How to clear excel sheet upon opening file
Anyone know how to clear worksheet upon opening your file? I'm trying to make a fool proof excel sheet we can deploy for reports at my work. I know how to clear it upon closing but not opening. The issue with clearing when closed is if they save the file prior to closing it will save the old report. So either need to clear it upon open or clear it prior to save. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks
I have tried clear on close. Need other methods to prevent old report being saved.

There's a Workbook_Open event you trigger code to run in. Toss your Clear code in there.

If they do not enable macros to run, it doesn't particularly matter if they have on _open or _beforesave.  It may behoove you to simply have a blank template, rather than clearing information?

So I have a button to trigger the macro then I have an api call within the macro that gets the data then the macro runs and formats the data accordingly and creates the report sheet. So I need that report sheet cleared each time so people don't use an old report. Fool proof

Why not make a copy of a hidden "template" worksheet and fill that?  No worries about needing to reset the sheet.  Also if people save a report don't they expect it to stay filled when they go back to it?  Maybe you can expand a little bit on your exact use case here.

As other have stated; using a template file is probably the best way to go, but to expand upon that; a .xltm file can have macros within it but when double clicked it will open as a .xlsm file so there is little risk of over-writing the template file. This means you can have a fresh workbook each time.

You can clear worksheet or do something else when you are opening your workbook. In this case, VBA code of three lines can clear your worksheet.
Track Workbook_Open() event.
From Excel menu Select [Developer] from ribbon then [Visual Basic] button. This action will open [Visual Basic For Application] environment. In the left side there are tree of objects with hierarchy. In the tree of [VBA Project]->Microsoft Excel objects there is [This WorkBook]. Just double click on it. and paste the following code on the right side window. Here, I apply it on a particular sheet named "File Data". You may need to change the worksheet name other than "File Data". If you want to clear all the existing sheets, that is also possible with 3/4 lines of additional codes.
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim ws As New Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("File Data")
    ws.Cells.Clear
End Sub

I successfully tested it on Microsoft Excel 2016.
Please knock me here, in case of any problems to implement it.
Thank you.
